# How to use single quote separated values from an array in a string prepared by using implode?

Tags: php, arrays, string, implode

I've following array called `$user_id_arr`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 92ecd33db4ddcdc28e025cae80f00208
    [1] => 9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d
    [2] => a6d22e4cc3f65778a60b359842bcec82
)
```

Now I want a string containing above array values but each array value should be enclosed in single quotes. For it I tried following code but not succeed.

```
$user_ids = implode(",", $user_id_arr);
```

I'm getting following array:

```
92ecd33db4ddcdc28e025cae80f00208,9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d,a6d22e4cc3f65778a60b359842bcec82
```

Can anyone please help me in this regard please? I want the desired array in following format:

```
'92ecd33db4ddcdc28e025cae80f00208','9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d','a6d22e4cc3f65778a60b359842bcec82'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$ids = "'" . implode("','", $array) . "'"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `implode` as the above answers suggested. If you directly want to modify the array then you could make use of `array_walk()`.

```
<?php
$arr=Array
(
    0 => '92ecd33db4ddcdc28e025cae80f00208',
    1 => '9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d',
    2 => 'a6d22e4cc3f65778a60b359842bcec82',
);
array_walk($arr,function (&$val){ $val="'".$val."'";});
echo implode(',',$arr);     //<----- This is the one you wanted by the way...
print_r($arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
'92ecd33db4ddcdc28e025cae80f00208','9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d','a6d22e4cc3f65778a60b359842bcec82'

Array
(
    [0] => '92ecd33db4ddcdc28e025cae80f00208'
    [1] => '9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d'
    [2] => 'a6d22e4cc3f65778a60b359842bcec82'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$user_id_arr = array
(
    '0' => '92ecd33db4ddcdc28e025cae80f00208',
    '1' => '9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d',
    '2' => 'a6d22e4cc3f65778a60b359842bcec82'
);

$user_ids = "'". implode("','",$user_id_arr)."'";
echo $user_ids;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$user_ids = "'".implode("','", $arr)."'";
```

See [demo](https://eval.in/122240)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($user_id_arr as $r){
    $user_ids = $user_ids."'".$r."',";
}
```